# PHP SOAP with client certificate fail

Tags: php, ssl, soap

TLDR: I'm trying to perform SOAP request with self-signed client certificate, and it fails with exception "Could not connect to host".

The full story:

1) I used openssl to create `.pem` certificate with such command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 30 -keyout server.key -out server.pem
```

Then I enabled HTTPS at my local apache and configured it to use this as its `SSLCertificateFile`.

2) Then I created short PHP script to catch SOAP requests. It just logs everything it can and returns "OK". Not a good SOAP response, but don't bother about it at the moment. Checked it with `https://localhost/soap/` in my browser, it shows "bad certificate" warning (as expected) and then I seen "OK" catcher reponse.

3) Now it's time to send SOAP request to the catcher script. I'm using the following code (with local WSDL copy and SOAP service address decribed there as `https://localhost/soap/`):

```
    $stream_context = stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer'       => false,
            'verify_peer_name'  => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        ),
    ));

    $soap_params = array(
        'local_cert'     => 'path/to/certificate',
        'trace'          => true,
        'stream_context' => $stream_context,
    );

    $soap = new SoapClient(
        'path/to/wsdl',
        $soap_params
    );

    $result = $soap->__soapCall('methodName', array());
```

At the last line an exception comes: "Could not connect to host".
I even can remove stream context at all and the same result will be produced, so I think it does not affect the story. I also tried 'https' context instead and both 'ssl' and 'https' together. If I remove `local_cert` parameter, I see another message: "looks like we got no XML document", which can be interpreted as it received "OK" message.

I am running PHP 5.3.29.

So, the questions are:

1) Is 'ssl' stream context is meaningless under my PHP version or I am just using it incorrectly?

2) Is there any other way to force SOAP to use this certificate? (It's a customer requirement so I can't omit it).

**UPD**:
PHP documentation says that

*local_cert string*

*Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a **PEM encoded** file which contains your **certificate and private key**. It can optionally contain the certificate chain of issuers.*

So I've re-generated `.pem` by concatenating `.crt` and `.key` files, used it and it helped. Also I skipped using `$stream_context`.

**UPD2**: The questions above are still actual.